# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Tag to JspTag

Tags: jsp, weblogic, myfaces

I'm creating a web application with Spring, Hibernate, RichFaces, Myfaces running on WebLogic 10.3.5

This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <myfaces.version>2.2.0</myfaces.version>
    <tomahawk.version>1.1.14</tomahawk.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.1</commons-beanutils.version>
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-digester.version>2.1</commons-digester.version>
    <commons-logging.version>1.1.3</commons-logging.version>
    <jhighlight.version>1.0</jhighlight.version>
    <richfaces.version>3.3.3.Final</richfaces.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    <javassist.version>3.12.1.GA</javassist.version>
    <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- jUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Myfaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TomaHawk -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
        <version>${tomahawk.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSTL per RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- commons-beanutils per RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Collections per RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Digester per RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-digester.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Logging per RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jHighlight per RichFaces -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uwyn</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhighlight</artifactId>
        <version>${jhighlight.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- RichFaces -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>${richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${richfaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have no compilation errors.
I have the following settings in the Project Facets into Eclipse:

1. Dynamic Web Module 2.5
2. Java 1.6
3. Oracle WebLogic Web App Extensions 10.3.5

When I run it I got the following errors on every jsp page I'm trying to display:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Tag to JspTag

followed by each jsp or jsf tag it contains.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Tag to JspTag
<%  ^
}
```

Cannot cast from JspContext to PageContext

Type mismatch: cannot convert from LoadBundleTag to JspTag

etc etc...

Do you know how I could fix it?

I've noticed that if I put the following tag in the weblogic.xml file, the home page works, but for the other pages I got those errors:

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, we are running into the same issues. Have you found the root cause and can point us to the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are deploying you webapp on an Application Server (Weblogic) that already provides you with base Java EE libraries.

You probably have inside your WEB-INF/lib libraries that you needed to compile your code but shouldn't be deployed on the application server as they're already provided.

Search for `j2ee.jar` or `servletapi.jar` inside your webapp

One easy way for you to see which libraries contain the class JspTag inside your webapp is to do:

`grep -nr 'JspTag' *`

These libraries should not be inside your WEB-INF/lib folder as they are provided by the Application Server already